# How to user swagger-codegen to build a Strava library for ASP.NET Core 2.1?

Tags: asp.net-core-2.1, swagger-codegen, strava

I'm trying to use swagger-codegen to build a DLL of [Strava](https://developers.strava.com/docs/) that can be used in an ASP.NET Core 2.1 server application.

Attempt 1 - Following instructions on https://developers.strava.com/docs/#client-code

- `brew install swagger-codegen@2 maven`
- `/usr/local/opt/swagger-codegen@2/bin/swagger-codegen generate -i https://developers.strava.com/swagger/swagger.json -l aspnetcore -o /Users/sergeishevlyagin/dev/StravaASP-2/`
- `bin/sh build.sh`

I get a bunch of errors of this variety

> Models/ActivityType.cs(36,29): error CS0103: The name 'AlpineSki' does not exist in the current context [/Users/sergeishevlyagin/dev/StravaASP-2/src/IO.Swagger/IO.Swagger.csproj]
>   Models/ActivityType.cs(36,29): error CS0103: The name 'AlpineSki' does not exist in the current context [/Users/sergeishevlyagin/dev/StravaASP-2/src/IO.Swagger/IO.Swagger.csproj]

Full [gist](https://gist.github.com/sshevlyagin/5d168dca842e67b419b68b8eadcb6ae2)

Attempt 2 - Using swagger 3 instead

- `brew install swagger-codegen`
- `/usr/local/opt/swagger-codegen@3/bin/swagger-codegen generate -i https://developers.strava.com/swagger/swagger.json -l aspnetcore -o /Users/sergeishevlyagin/dev/StravaASP-3/`
- `bin/sh build.sh`

I get a bunch of errors of this variety:

> Controllers/ActivitiesApi.cs(54,160): error CS1001: Identifier expected [/Users/sergeishevlyagin/dev/StravaASP-3/src/IO.Swagger/IO.Swagger.csproj]
>   Models/BaseStream.cs(46,35): error CS1003: Syntax error, ',' expected [/Users/sergeishevlyagin/dev/StravaASP-3/src/IO.Swagger/IO.Swagger.csproj]
>   sergeishevlyagin/dev/StravaASP-3/src/IO.Swagger/IO.Swagger.csproj]
>   Controllers/ActivitiesApi.cs(54,160): error CS1001: Identifier expected [/Users/sergeishevlyagin/dev/StravaASP-3/src/IO.Swagger/IO.Swagger.csproj]
>   Models/BaseStream.cs(46,35): error CS1003: Syntax error, ',' expected [/Users/sergeishevlyagin/dev/StravaASP-3/src/IO.Swagger/IO.Swagger.csproj]

Full [gist](https://gist.github.com/sshevlyagin/7e2144213628ba65320630d9526c45e9)

Comment: Not sure about "Attempt 2", but the CS0103 errors in "Attempt 1" are caused by a bug in how Swagger Codegen generates .NET enums - https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/8751

Comment: Thanks Helen! Now to find a solution :D